# How to create a few radio boxes in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radio-button

yeah :( simple question * *blush* *

Lets imagine i have the following enumeration:-

```
string[] languages = new string[]
                     {
                         "en (uk)", // English (colour)
                         "en (us)", // English (color)
                         "fr", // French
                         "es" // Spanish
                     };

ViewData["Languages"] = languages;
ViewData["UserLanguage"] = "en (uk)";
```

Armed with this, how would i display a radio button in the View? Is the only way to do this to enumerate through all the language values and render a RadioBox?

eg. pseduo-code...

```
<% foreach(string language in ViewData["Languages"] as string[])
{
  response.write Html.RadioBox(... not sure what to set in here ...)
}%>
```

cheers!

Comment: I updated my answer and added a link to MVCFutures.(where the RadioButtonList method is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
<% foreach(string language in ViewData["Languages"] as string[]) { %>
  <%= Html.RadioBox(language,language,language == ViewData["UserLanguage"].ToString()) %>
<% } %>
```

The problem is that you have allot of magic strings in that viewdata. What I would do is something like this:

1. Create a class: UserForm

   ```
   class UserForm {

        IList<string> _languages;
        string _selectedL;

        public UserForm (IList<string> languages, string selectedLanguage)
        {
          _languages = languages;
          _selectedL = selectedLanguage;
        }

        IEnumerable<SelectedListItem> UserLanguages {
            get {
                 return from l in _languages
                         select new SelectedListItem {
                             Text = l,
                             Value = l,
                             Selected = (l == _selectedL)
                         };
            }
        }
   }
   ```
2. the view should be strongly typed and be of type : UserForm
   then you could render it like :

   ```
   <%= Html.RadioButtonList("userLanguages",ViewData.Model.UserLanguages) %>
   ```
3. From the controller you would :

   ```
   return View(new UserForm(listOfLanguages, selectedLanguage));
   ```

HTH.

**EDIT:**
OK, found it - the `RadioButtonList` is an extension method in the `Microsoft.Web.Mvc` namespace (the MVCFutures project) - you can get it from here : [MVCFutures](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471)

Comment: AFAIK, Html.RadioButtonList doesn't exist anymore ... can u confirm?

Comment: Well , I haven't yet switched to the RTM , so you are probably correct :| . I wonder what the reason was.